# Collectionview animated

Tags: ios, swift, animation, layout, uicollectionview

I have collection view with items, each item has dimension (65 * 65) with horizontal flow, and I have button.

So when I click on the button all items must stack over first item, then I need to make collection layout vertically (like table view).

How to make it (with animation)?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if self.isClose {
            return CGSizeMake(50, 50)
        }else{
            if self.isOpen {
                return CGSizeMake(320, 50)
            }else {
                return CGSizeMake(50, 50)
            }
        }

    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNvV.png)

Comment: how to you want to perform animation exactly ? should they move in some pattern or just go on the first item from where ever they are ?

Comment: like this image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNvV.png)

Comment: try to deleteItemsAtIndexPaths for each one so after some time i will have one item

Comment: how to make layout as album???

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3 and 4**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SSProductCell {
            cell.imageView.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SSProductCell {
            cell.imageView.transform = .identity
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```